# Problem with AWS beanstalk and github CD workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment

I am doing this tutorial

[CICD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSNMA-ftK4s&list=PLaLqLOj2bk9ZV2RhqXzABUP5QSg42uJEs&index=7)

He deployed the project easily, but with the new AWS interface, it's necessary to configure the environment correctly. I've tried many configurations, but I continue to get the following error.

```
10:42:55 WARN: The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-02a53cf6187393064].
10:42:55 INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1].
10:42:55 ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-02a53cf6187393064'. Aborting the operation.
10:42:55 ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
10:42:55 ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
10:43:13 ERROR: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: null, Health: Grey, Health Status: null
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: null, Health: Grey, Health Status: null
```

My Github workflow file

```
name: Deploy on QA

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy_on_qa:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Source Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Create customer Env file
        working-directory: ./customer
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo APP_SECRET=${{ secrets.QA_APP_SECRET }} >> .env
          echo MONGODB_URI=${{ secrets.QA_CUSTOMER_DB_URL }} >> .env
          echo MSG_QUEUE_URL=${{ secrets.QA_MSG_QUEUE_URL }} >> .env
          echo EXCHANGE_NAME=ONLINE_STORE >> .env
          echo PORT=8001 >> .env
          cat .env
      - name: Create Products Env file
        working-directory: ./products
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo APP_SECRET=${{ secrets.QA_APP_SECRET }} >> .env
          echo MONGODB_URI=${{ secrets.QA_PRODUCTS_DB_URL }} >> .env
          echo MSG_QUEUE_URL=${{ secrets.QA_MSG_QUEUE_URL }} >> .env
          echo EXCHANGE_NAME=ONLINE_STORE >> .env
          echo PORT=8002 >> .env
          cat .env
          
      - name: Create shopping Env file
        working-directory: ./shopping
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo APP_SECRET=${{ secrets.QA_APP_SECRET }} >> .env
          echo MONGODB_URI=${{ secrets.QA_SHOPPING_DB_URL }} >> .env
          echo MSG_QUEUE_URL=${{ secrets.QA_MSG_QUEUE_URL }} >> .env
          echo EXCHANGE_NAME=ONLINE_STORE >> .env
          echo PORT=8003 >> .env
          cat .env
          
      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: |
          zip -r deploy-versio-82.zip . -x '*.git'
      
      - name: Deploy on Elastic beanstalk QA Env
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: test-qa
          environment_name: Test-qa-env
          version_label: "ver-${{ github.sha }}"
          region: eu-central-1
          deployment_package: deploy-versio-82.zip
          use_existing_version_if_available: true`
```

could someone help me?

I tried to change configuration and restart AWS Beanstalk environment
And some Github workflow file configurations

I'm trying to deploy the application